Requesting a Snapshot from within a cluster node
According to the Aeron Cluster documentation, snapshots should be initiated via the ClusterTool or via aeronCluster.sendAdminRequestToTakeASnapshot.
On top of these two options is there a way to request taking a snapshot from within a cluster node?
Reason for asking is that we'd rather not have an additional/separate service with the sole purpose of requesting snapshots.
We tried sending an AdminRequest via cluster.offer but this wraps the AdminRequest into SessionMessage, and therefore does not trigger taking a snapshot.
